# Return values where each statement is true Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am attempting to return records where multiple fields may be missing values. I have the following statement:

```
IF ISNULL([Sales Team]) THEN 'Sales Team'
   ELSEIF ISNULL([Portfolio]) THEN 'Portfolio'
   ELSEIF ISNULL([Category Type]) THEN 'Category Type'
   ELSEIF [Datasource] = 'DS1' AND ISNULL([Item Class Dtl]) THEN 'Item Class Dtl'
   ELSEIF ISNULL([Market]) THEN 'Market'
END
```

If Sales Team and Portfolio are NULL in a single record I want to return Sales Team and Portfolio amounts under their respective rows. Due to the nature of the `ELSEIF`, Portfolio amounts are excluded when Sales Team is NULL.

My end goal is to take this from 10 workbooks in a dashboard down to two. I am currently making the check for NULLS on a singular basis and combining the results in a dashboard.

**From this:**
[image]

**To this:**
[image]

Is there another Tableau function I can use to achieve this or another way to rewrite this? Thanks!

Comment: _"If Sales Team and Portfolio are NULL in a single record I want to return Sales Team and Portfolio amounts"_  What does the formula look like that returns the amounts?  I think **that** is where you would consolidate the multiple calculated fields I've recommended below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this out into separate calculated fields.
So, for example, the Sales Team calc would look like:

```
IF ISNULL([Sales Team]) THEN 'Sales Team' END
```

Create one calculated field for each condition.  You can then get multiple "true" results from a single record.

---

In response to the updated question:

> If Sales Team and Portfolio are NULL in a single record I want to
>   return Sales Team and Portfolio amounts

So, the consolidation of the multiple calculated formulas would happen in the formula that calculates the amount.  I don't currently know what that amount formula looks like, so I will give a general example.

Formula that tests for NULL (Let's call this `Sales Team Check`) would look like:

```
IF ISNULL([Sales Team]) THEN [Sales Team Amount] ELSE 0 END
```

You would have a formula for each condition.
Then, the consolidating formula would look like:

```
[Sales Team Check] + [Portfolio Check] + [Category Type Check] + [Datasource Check] + [Market Check]
```

The idea here is that instead of returning Text when you check the record for a NULL field, you return the amount, otherwise return zero.  Then add up the result of those checks.

Comment: Check my edits. I am currently using multiple calculated fields and views and would like this in a single view.

Comment: Also learn about the ZN() and IFNULL() functions if you haven't already. They can can be useful for simplifying similar logic in some cases.