# Classify and filter entries based on string in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to filter based on substrings within a string. These strings can contain A through E, or any combination of the five (such as ["C"] or ["A","C","D","E"]). Is there a way I could search through the entire string for each letter before returning a value?

The code I have currently (below) stops when the first IF statement is true. My goal is to be able to classify the entries by the letters in the string and use this calculation as a filter. So, an entry with the string ["A"] would be filtered under "A", but the string ["C","E"] would be filtered under both "C" and "E". Thank you for your help.

```
IF CONTAINS([Q2.6],"A") then "A"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Q2.6],"B") then "B"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Q2.6],"C") then "C"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Q2.6],"D") then "D"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Q2.6],"E") then "E"
END
```

Comment: You'll need to write a conditional statement (or switch statement) that covers each possible combination.  It might also be possible by assigning a different numeric value to "A","B","C","D" and "E" and then determining the components based on the sum, but you'd have to pick numbers that always lead to unique sums so that you're able to determine the components of the sum.  I'm not 100% sure that's possible.

Comment: @devlincarnate answered this for me some time ago. Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184589/return-values-where-each-statement-is-true-tableau